# Offset out of range resetting offset 2nd consumer group

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Offset is getting reset when single topic is consumed by two different consumer groups.

I am using Kafka version 0.10.1.0 and Spring-Kafka version 2.2.4 Release.
I produce a message in topic "topic_X" which should be consumed by two different consumer groups "consumerA" and "consumerB" with single consumers each.

Lets say "consumerB" is down I have produced 100 messages on "topic_X" and "consumerA" is already running and consumed all of them. When I bring "consumberB" up again the offset is set to 100 instead of starting from 0.

I have tried by setting auto-offset-reset:earliest and still it is not working. Below are the logs I got from console.

When I start the "consumberB" I dont want to reset the offset how can do that?

```
2019-05-15 11:28:44.309  INFO 16152 --- [eted-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=consumer_group] (Re-)joining group
2019-05-15 11:28:44.536  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2019-05-15 11:28:44.539  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_x-0]
2019-05-15 11:28:44.788  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [topic_x-0]
2019-05-15 11:28:45.906  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Fetch offset 5411 is out of range for partition topic_x-0, resetting offset
2019-05-15 11:28:46.187  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Resetting offset for partition topic_x-0 to offset 5651.
2019-05-15 11:28:47.864  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2019-05-15 11:28:48.142  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic_x-0]
2019-05-15 11:28:48.142  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [topic_x-0]
2019-05-15 11:28:48.142  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] (Re-)joining group
2019-05-15 11:28:48.976  INFO 16152 --- [eted-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=consumer_group] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2019-05-15 11:28:48.976  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2019-05-15 11:28:48.976  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=consumer_group] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_x-0]
2019-05-15 11:28:48.976  INFO 16152 --- [eted-Data-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=consumer_group] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_y-0]
2019-05-15 11:28:49.246  INFO 16152 --- [ment-Data-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [topic_x-0]
```

Below is the code I am using to create consumer. Another consumer in group "consumerA" is already running in different application. When I start my application consumer in group "consumerB" the offset is getting reset.

```
@KafkaListener(id="client-1", topics= "topic_x", groupId = "consumerB")
    public void completed(final byte[] bytes) throws IOException {

        //Handler code

    }
```

Comment: You mean two different consumers "consumerA" and "consumerB" right ? Not consumer group. Check if both are not in the same consumer group. If these are the only two you're creating.

Comment: Two different consumer groups.

Comment: Can you show how you're creating them ?

Comment: Looks like some problem with the broker - I just googled it and found [this](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/972). 0.10.x.x is very old; you should really upgrade to a newer broker (currently 2.2.0).

Comment: Ill check this with the new version. Thanks @GaryRussell